# The key value of one object is changing on update of other similar type of object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using two different array object `initialPermissionArr[item.id]` and `newPermissionArr[roleId]` in two different functions

```
function(item){


    vm.initialPermissionArr[item.id] = item.permissions.map(function (permission) {
       permission.status = true;
       return permission;
    });
}


        staticArr[item.id] = item.permissions.map(function (permission) {
            permission.status = true;
            return permission;
        });

        newpermissionArr[item.id] = vm.initialPermissionArr[item.id];
```

Below function updates the array, if same object is found it updates the status and if new object is found it pushes to newPermissionArr

```
function onChanageOfPermission(roleId,item) {
   var flag = false ;
   for (var key in newpermissionArr[roleId]){
      if(newPermissionArr[roleId][key].id == item.id){
         flag = true;
         newPermissionArr[roleId][key].status = item.status;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (!flag) {
      newPermissionArr[roleId].push(item);
   }
}
```

So when `newPermissionArr[roleId][key].status = item.status;` is updated it also update the status in the `initialPermissionArr[item.id]`  also. 
And initial declaration is

```
var newPermissionArr = [];
var staticArr = [];
```

where for eg item is

```
{
  roleId : 1,
  permissions : [{"name": "A", "id" : 1},{ "name" : "B", "id" : 2 }]
}
```

I need initial object Array to remain same and at the end i need to compare the initial array with the  modified array and need to find the reference however on updating the status it updates in both array. How to avoid this ?

Comment: Both `arrays` probably have a reference to the same `object`?

Comment: where can be reference be same, I am not copying anywhere to each other

Comment: Hard to tell when you have not included how/when you use `onChangeOfPermission`, and what you pass in as `item`.

Comment: can it  be the issue,
a = b;
c = b;
so will a and c are ref to same;

Comment: The items references are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of following line of code

`newpermissionArr[item.id] = vm.initialPermissionArr[item.id];`

Here object is passed by reference, so whenever newpermission is updated intialpermission will also be updated.

To fix this just copy the intialPermissionArr to newPermissionArr.
Unfortunately,plain javascript does not have any function like `angular.copy`. So you will have to do this in following way-

`newrPermissionArr[item.id] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.intialPermissionArr[item.id]));`

this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The arrays reference the same object. To modify just one of them, you should use slice() function for clone the array:

```
    newpermissionArr[item.id] = vm.initialPermissionArr[item.id].slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign something to a and b and it is a pointer in memory to object c. Then as soon as you change it to c2 both a and b will get c2 from that point as they were just pointers to same location.